# Can i have multiple google api keys in one project

Tags: google-maps, multiple-instances, api-key

I have a service that currently uses one google maps api key. i want to separate that into individual keys for all websites that use that service. is it possible to switch between google api keys based on where the request is coming from and also count the usage / analytics against that account which key i am using.

p.s. Taking over from different person who tells me that is not possible as the key is tied to serverIP which in my case wold not change.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about client API keys for the Google Maps JavaScript API. Those keys are tied to your domain (such as stackoverflow.com). You can create different keys for different domains, if the different web sites that you manage are on different domains. If all the web sites you manage are on the same domain, you can't use different keys. You can also use subdomains though with different keys, as long as you set up each key on a different subdomain. That may not work for your situation.